# Removing backticks in R output

Tags: r

I have certain variables that `lm` in R automatically wraps with backticks/back quotes, e.g. variables that have colons in the names.

After some processing, I'm trying to write out the variables and coefficients of the linear model with `write.table`. Unfortunately, the backticks are written out as well.

How can I prevent these backticks from being written?

To give a simple but unrealistic example:

```
d <- data.frame(`1`=runif(10), y=runif(10), check.names=F)
l <- lm(y ~ `1`, d)
write.table(data.frame(l$coefficients), file="lm.coeffs", quote=F, sep="\t", col.names=F)
```

The file `lm.coeffs` will--quite obviously--have `` `1` `` in the first column of the output rather than `1`. Outside of postprocessing in some other script, how do I remove backticks from output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that *post-processing* in R. Instead of a file, store the output in a variable using `capture.output`. Remove the backticks using `gsub`. Finally, print the output to a file using `cat`:

```
report <- capture.output(write.table(data.frame(l$coefficients),
                         quote = FALSE, sep = "\t", col.names = FALSE))

cat(gsub("`", "", report), sep = "\n", file = "lm.coeffs")
```

Comment: +1 I'd never thought of what `write.table` returns invisibly!