# Avoiding backtick characters with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rodbc

How can I write the argument of `select` without backtick characters? I would like to do this so that I can pass in this argument from a variable as a character string.

```
df <- dat[["__Table"]] %>% select(`__ID` ) %>% mutate(fk_table = "__Table", val = 1)
```

Changing the argument of select to `"__ID"` gives this error:

```
Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  "__ID"
```

Unfortunately, the `_` characters in column names cannot be avoided since the data is downloaded from a relational database (FileMaker) via ODBC and needs to be written back to the database while preserving the column names.

Ideally, I would like to be able to do the following:

```
colName <- "__ID"    
df <- dat[["__Table"]] %>% select(colName) %>% mutate(fk_table = "__Table", val = 1)
```

I've also tried `eval(parse())`:

```
df <- dat[["__Table"]] %>% select( eval(parse(text="__ID")) ) %>% mutate(fk_table = "__Table", val = 1)
```

It throws this error:

```
Error in parse(text = "__ID") : <text>:1:1: unexpected input
1: _
    ^
```

By the way, the following does work, but then I'm back to square one (still with backtick symbol).

```
eval(parse(text="`__ID`")
```

References about backtick characters in `R`:

- [Removing backticks in R output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430845/removing-backticks-in-r-output)
- [What do backticks do in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220823/what-do-backticks-do-in-r)
- [R encoding ASCII backtick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353174/r-encoding-ascii-backtick?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: You should look at using `select_()` (and the other underscore versions of `dplyr` functions).

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569154 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `as.name()` with `select_()`:

```
colName <- "__ID"
df <- data.frame(`__ID` = c(1,2,3), `123` = c(4,5,6), check.names = FALSE)
select_(df, as.name(colName))
```

Comment: The OP wants to pass in variables, not use character strings.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Well, this should work fine with `var <- "__ID"; select_(df, as.name(var))` too, no ?

Comment: @StevenBeaupré Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I've made a small edit to your answer so it uses a variable to hold the column name, but that was just a trivial change. Thanks for letting me know about `as.name()`